# how to check how many pooled connection we have at a specific time in MemSQL

Tags: singlestore

How can i tell that i have reached the maximum number of queries that my cluster can handle at a time?

If the connection pool size is too small for the workload then we have to  adjust the max_pooled_connections configuration variable, which controls the number of pooled connections between each pair of nodes.

However how can I tell how many pooled connections we have at a specific time ?

In memsql agregator status i can see following entries     Aborted_connects is 11  - why do we abort those connection ?    Also Max_used_connections is 41, while Connections is a number that increases constantly.

Comment: Also I can see that increasing the number of aggregators will improve operations like data loading and will allow MemSQL to process more client requests concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i tell that i have reached the maximum number of queries that
>   my cluster can handle at a time?

There isn't a hard limit on the number of queries you can send other than max_connections (100k), but at some point the cluster will not execute them all at once and will schedule/queue them up. Is your question about the former or the latter?

> If the connection pool size is too small for the workload then we have
>   to adjust the max_pooled_connections configuration variable, which
>   controls the number of pooled connections between each pair of nodes.
>
> However how can I tell how many pooled connections we have at a
>   specific time ?

`show leaves` will show how many connections are currently open from the current node to each leaf. So the current connection pool size is min(current open connections, max_pooled_connections). Note that this is per (node, node) pair.

> In memsql agregator status i can see following entries
>   Aborted_connects is 11 - why do we abort those connection ? Also
>   Max_used_connections is 41, while Connections is a number that
>   increases constantly.

Aborted connects includes e.g. failed login authentications.

max_used_connections is max peak, connections is cumulative total.